# CUDA bandwidth in single precison and bandwidth in double precison

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to determinate my PC bandwidth with CUDA. I have a 750M bord and my theoretical bandwidth is 90 GB, in specification is mention like 80GB. I have tried a simple algorithm from the nvidia website https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/.
I have change the code for single precison and double precison and i have this results:

Single precison(float) : 30GB/s

Double precison : 26GB/s

The bandwidth for single precison is calculated like this:

```
 printf("Effective Bandwidth (GB/s): %fn", N*4*3/milliseconds/1e6);
```

And if i try to make it for double precison (8 bytes) :

```
printf("Effective Bandwidth (GB/s): %fn", N*8*3/milliseconds/1e6);
```

The rezult for double precison is bigger then single precison :

Single precison(float) : 30 GB/s

Double precison : 45 GB/s

Answer (score 0):

Using this approach, you are making 32 bits loads. The memory management unit for your card does not have the necessary resources (requests in flight - see Little Law and memory latency [this](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2016/EECS-2016-143.pdf) technical report seems to cover it) for the bandwidth to perform at full performance.

You want to use 128 bits loads (using float4 for example) to maximize your bandwidth, or at least float2, and perform several operations for each thread.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice material.

Comment: If this answers your question, maybe you want to mark it as such ?